# Xvfb and scripts on Ubuntu Touch/Phone

Tags: python, ubuntu-touch, headless, xvfb

Will I be able to run "xvfb" on Ubuntu Touch/Phone? I've read that you can use `apt-get` and use `bash`. So will I also be able to run Python scripts which use "Selenium" and "Xvfb" for headless Firefox website testing on Ubuntu Touch/Phone?

Maybe someone who has access to a device already running it could test it and tell me.